American option PDE
I'm reading the pdf here regarding the PDE associated with the American option. Essentially, one would turn the Black Scholes PDE into an inequality.
Suppose you're pricing an American put where $S$ is the stock price and $E$ is the exercise price. Why can't $V = max(E-S,0)$ be the solution to the American option PDE? It satisfies all the constraints: the terminal condition, never dropping below the stock payoff, and the inequality arising from the PDE. Clearly, $V = max(E-S,0)$ is not the right answer since it convers no extrinsic value. However, how do I reconcile with this wrong solution with the PDE formulated in the pdf?

Pls add details to your question so that it can still be understood or answered even if the link you have provided is broken.

I don't think what you said is true. Sometimes, the future expected value of the option is greater than $V=max(E-S,0)$. This can be visualized in the context of a binomial tree, where the risk-neutral probabilities can be used to compute a future expected value of the American put such that it can be used to compare to the current intrinsic value of that American put.

I'm not saying $V = max(E-S,0)$ is the option price. It is not, but it does satisfy the conditions outlined in the pdf. How do I reconcile this apparent contradiction?

@user1691278 If you think that non differentiable function $\max(E-S,0)$ satisfies all the conditions outlined in the pdf then please elaborate in OP in detail. Good luck!

@user1691278 as Kurt G. has mentioned, please outline those conditions mentioned in the PDF so we may help you.
